# why scale a normal distribution by the square root of the variance?

Tags: probability

Given a standard normal distribution $N(0,1)$ why, if you wish to scale it, you need to multiply by the square root of the variance? 
Ie given a variance t, the new scaled distribution is $N(0, t)$ which is equivalent to $\sqrt{t}*N(0,1)$?

Isn't the pdf of the general normal $\frac{1}{\sigma}$*(standard normal pdf)?
An intuitive explanation and proof would be quite helpful.

Comment: In $N(0,1)$, $0$ stands for the mean $μ$ and $1$ stands for the variance $σ^2$ or for the standard deviation $σ$?

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: The variance is a quadratic thing. $\operatorname{Var}(cX) = c^2\operatorname{Var}(X)$, immediately from the definitions.

Answer (score 4):

Generally if $X$ is a random variable with mean $μ$ and Variance $σ^2$, then for any scalar $t$ you can prove that $E[tX]=tE[X]$ and $Var(tX)=t^2Var(X)$. So, if $X\sim N(0,1)$ and you want to create a random variable $Y\sim N(0,t)$ (where $t$ denotes the variance and not the standard deviation), then $$t=Var(Y)=Var(kX)=k^2Var(X)=k^2\cdot1=k^2 \implies k=\pm \sqrt{t}$$

Comment: so my original note of the general normal formula being $\frac{1}{\sigma}$*standard normal pdf is irrelevant?

Comment: Perhaps you confuse it with the reverse transformation: If $X\sim N(0,σ^2)$ with $σ>0$, then $$Z=\frac{X}{σ}\sim N(0,1)$$